# Link classes in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I have two classes as follows A.h contains

```
public ref class A
{
public:
 A(void);
 B ^_ObjB;
}
```

In A.cpp I have used methods from class B using _ObjB->Method().

Now in my class B , I have certain methods which will require methods from class A to be called so I tried to declare it in following way-

```
public ref class B
{
public:
 B(A);
 A ^_ObjA;
}
```

Obvious it is not right way to do it so it throwing erros. I would like to know what How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you do in regular C++, I guess:

```
//A.h
public ref class B;

public ref class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    B ^_ObjB;
};
```

```
//B.h
public ref class A;

public ref class B
{
public:
    B(A^);
    A ^_ObjA;
};
```